# Boost 1.48.0 on Fedora Core 16

Tags: gcc, boost, fedora

I'm trying to install ONLY the Boost Libraries 1.48.0 that are 100% complete from FC17 on an FC16 system. I have scoured the net but can't figure out how to do it. I have attempted to upgrade to rawhide but there are too many broken dependencies. I was hoping to just be able to upgrade that one package, as hopefully I don't believe I have too many programs installed that depend on Boost libraries (just the ones I'm coding).

I need to use the new features in 1.48.0. If I can't install them via an RPM, can I compile them as a normal user, store them in ~/lib and link against them?

I'm on FC16 x86_64.

Comment: If you can find the `.spec` file then you could just `rpmbuild` an F16 version of the RPM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just need to export several shell environment variables in your shell profile to tell the compiler where to find your new boost header files and shared object files.

```
# For C and C++ header files search path
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$your_new_boost_include_dir:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$your_new_boost_include_dir:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

# link path
export LIBRARY_PATH=$your_new_boost_lib_dir:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

Usually you'll also need to do the following so that the compiled executables can be linked to the right version of shared object files at run time:

```
# run-time
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$your_new_boost_lib_dir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```